# why Angular doesn't complain when Routes is passed instead of Route

Tags: angular6

When creating routes, I believe we create an array of type `Routes` and pass it to `forRoots` method of `RouterModule`. But `forRoot` seem to expect `Route`, not `Routes`. Why Angular doesn't complain?

`AppRoutes` is of type `Routes`

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
      { path: 'hero/:id', `enter code here`     component: HeroDetailComponent }];
```

But RouterModule's `forRoot` expects `Route[]`

```
class RouterModule {
  static forRoot(routes: Route[], config?: ExtraOptions): ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule>
  static forChild(routes: Route[]): ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route` is the interface. While `Routes` is an array of that interface. You can check it in the `config.d.ts` file

**config.d.ts**

[image]

[image]

Comment: So something like ‘Routes = Route[] ‘??